# Why use linked lists, if at the end time complexity from arrays for deletion/insertion is equal?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I have following question. Why use Linked List, if time complexity for deletion of element for arrays is O(n) and for Linked List(with index given) is also O(n) since I also need to search through whole list?

Comment: It's `O(1)` if you have already found the element you want to delete, which is often the case.

Comment: But I need to  first find the element before I delete it. How else should I know where it is?

Comment: Often, you've found the element already. E.g. (1) Find element, (2) do something with element, (3) delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the asymptotic complexity may be the same, the constant factor may be very different.  In particular, you might have a collection of "large" things that are expensive to move or copy, but cheap to match.  So with the linked list, you do a (fast) O(n) seach to find an element, then a O(1) to insert/remove there.  With the array you need the same O(n) search and then a slow O(n) move of all the other elements in the array to make/remove space.

It is also possible you may have another connected data structure (such as a hash table) with fast lookup ability giving references into your collection.  In such a case, you can find an element in the list in O(1) time, then remove it in O(1) time.

Another advantage is that lists are more amenable to atomic update -- a single-link list can be updated (insert or remove) with a single (atomic) pointer write.